# magento 1.9 one concrete product is not displaying on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product

All the products are displayed on the store correctly, but one concrete product is not displaying on frontend. This product is a configurable product, and was visible some time ago.

I checked the following steps:

- I reindexed all and cleaned all the caches, the product is still not
  visible.
- Product is enabled
- Visibility is set on 'Catalog, Search'
- Product is added to all websites
- Product is asigned to more than one category, the cateories are visible
- Product inventory is set to 'manage stock' and is 'in stock'
- Simple associated products (childs) to this configurable product are 'in stock' and have stock quantity greater than 0
- Product has images
- Category display mode is set to display products, actually is displaying the rest of products.
- Copy the url key from backend/catalog/product and paste it in the browser displays a 404

And after checking all this points I have no idea why this product is not displaying on front.

Comment: All child products are in stock?

Comment: Not all of them. It has 6 childs, 3 in stock and 3 out of stock. But it is not suposing a problem in other configurable products, they are displayed while at least one of the child have stock.

Comment: Try to check URL key in URL Rewrite Management.

Comment: Finally I've found the problem, somebody has disabled the product in the language views, while I was checking the `All store views` and I saw it enabled, it was disabled in each of the store views. Now the product is displayed correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Great!! happy to help you!!

Comment: @Alex you should post your solution and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem, the store has different views. One view for each language.

Somebody has disabled the product in each one of the language views, while I was checking the All store views and I saw it enabled, it was disabled in each of the store views.

I selected the store view of one of the languages, changed the product to enabled, and then the same in each one of the store views.

**So, if you have a multilanguage store, remember to look always also the store views, maybe they have a different value than the default one.**

Now the product is displayed correctly.

Comment: this would have saved you a lot of time I guess: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_ScopeHint2